Proof of stacks lemma 34.9.14 regarding conditions for fpqc sheaf
I’m looking at the proof of lemma 34.9.14 from Stacks project. The situation: We are trying to show that given an fpqc covering $\{f_i:U_i\to X\}$ and a functor $F:Sch\to Set^{op}$ that satisfies:

$F$ is a sheaf in the Zariski topology

For every faithfully flat morphism $V\to U$ of affine schemes, the induced diagram
$$F(U)\to F(V)\rightrightarrows F(V\times_U V)$$ is an equalizer


Then $F$ is a sheaf in the fpqc topology. The proof starts by letting $s_i\in F(U_i)$ be a collection of sections such that $F(pr^1_{ij})(s_i)=F(pr^2_{ij})(s_j)$ (where $pr^1_{ij}$ and $pr^2_{ij}$ are the projections from $U_i\times_X U_j\to U_i$, and similarly for $j$).
The proof lets $W$ be the maximal open subset such that there exists a section $s\in F(W)$ such that for all $i$, $s_i|_{f_{i}^{-1}(W)}=s|_{f_i^{-1}(W)}$ (abusing notation, having $s|_{f_i^{-1}(W)}=F(f_i|_{f_i^{-1}(W)}(s)$).
Specifically, the proof claims that because of the Zariski property (property 1.), $W$ is the union of all open subsets with this property. It then shows that for every point of $X$, any affine open neighborhood satisfies this property.
What I am failing to see is given $W$ and $W’$ open subsets and $s\in F(W),s’\in F(W’)$ such that for all $i$, $s|_{f_{i}^{-1}(W)}=s_i|_{f_i^{-1}(W)}$ and $s’|_{f_{i}^{-1}(W’)}=s_i|_{f_i^{-1}(W’)}$, why should $s|_{W\cap W’}=s’|_{W\cap W’}$ (as the Zariski sheaf condition of $F$ would imply that we can glue to a section $s’’$ on $W\cup W’$ that restricts to $W$ and $W’$)? If we have this agreement, I can show that the $t_j$ glue to a global section $s$ whose pullbacks along $f_i$ give $s_i$. Any help is appreciated. (I know this same result is Lemma 2.60 from Angelo Vistoli’s notes, but I am trying to understand this particular argument).

I'm wondering whether there should be a short argument showing first that $F(U) \to \prod_{i} F(U_{i})$ is injective for all coverings $\{U_{i} \to U\}$ (using that every covering has a refinement by a standard fpqc covering). Then we could show that $s|_{W \cap W'} = s'|_{W \cap W'}$ by applying this injectivity to the covering $\{U_{i} \times_{X} (W \cap W') \to W \cap W'\}$.
